# Fire event when panel backcolor changes from (specific) one to another

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to fire an event when a panels `BackColor` changes from one specific color to another.

Pseudo example when the panel changes from Green to Orange.

```
If Panel.BackColor = Color.Green Changes To
Panel1.BackColor = Color.Orange
Then
Fire An Event
```

I know you can add the `BackColorChanged` handler but I have no clue how to compare these specific colors with each other.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add  previous color in array or list or even in string variable

```
    Dim arr(1) As String
    Private Sub Panel1_BackColorChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.BackColorChanged

        arr(0) = arr(1)
        arr(1) = Panel1.BackColor.ToString

        If arr(0) = "orange" And arr(1) = "green" Then
            'do someting
        End If
    End Sub
```